# user login form vb6 error

Tags: vb6, eof

**hi,
i write programme in vb6 and depend on ms access database 
i create table in ms access (users)
then i make module :-**

```
Public DB As New ADODB.Connection
Public RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Public RSS As New ADODB.Recordset
Public SQLS As String
Public UserNames As String
Public UserPassword As String

Sub POOLCONNECTION()
    If DB.State = adStateOpen Then DB.Close
    DB.Provider = "Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0"
    DB.Open App.Path & "\data.mdb"
End Sub
```

**and i make some forms for user :-
1- i make check user form to create administrator user for the first time to** use. if there are no records this form will create admin user
code:-

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Text1 = " "
    Text2 = " "
    Text3 = " "

    POOLCONNECTION
    SQLS = " Select * From Users "
    If RS.State = adStateOpen Then RS.Close
    RS.Open SQLS, DB, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic

    If Not RS.RecordCount = 0 Then
       FRMLOGIN.Show
       Unload Me
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub save_Click()
    If Text1 = " " Then
        MsgBox " Sorry, You Must Type Username ", vbCritical +  vbMsgBoxRight, "Error"
        Text1.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Text2 = " " Then
        MsgBox " Please Type Old Password ", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxRight, "  Error "
        Text2.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    SaveMsg = MsgBox(" åá ÊÑíÏ ÇäÔÇÁ ãÏíÑ ááäÙÇã ?", vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxRight + vbYesNo, " Êã ÇáÍÝÙ  ")

    If SaveMsg = vbYes Then
        RS.AddNew
        RS![UserName] = Text1
        RS![Password] = Text2
        RS![GAdd] = True
        RS![GEdit] = True
        RS![GPrint] = True
        RS![GCreateUser] = True
        RS![GDelete] = True
        RS.Update

        MsgBox " Êã ÍÝÙ ÇáÈíÇäÇÊ", vbInformation + vbMsgBoxRight, " Saved "
        ' Save This Informations
        UserNames = Text1
        UserPassword = Text2
        ' Long Main

        Set RS = Nothing
        Set DB = Nothing
        MDIForm1.Show
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

**for the second time use after i have making adimn user login form show and i try to login with the admin user .. eof didn't read the records
login code :**

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If Text1 = "" Or Text2 = "" Then
        MsgBox " ÚÝæÇ íÌÈ ßÊÇÈÉ ÇÓã ÇáãÓÊÎÏã æßáãÉ ÇáãÑæÑ ", vbCritical +  vbMsgBoxRight, " ÎØÃ Ýì ÇáÏÎæá"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    SQLS = "Select * From Users Where Username = ' " & Text1 & " '  And  Password = ' " & Text2 & " ' "

    If RS.State = adStateOpen Then RS.Close

    RS.Open SQLS, DB, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic

    If RS.EOF Then
        MsgBox " Sorry, The Username And Password Is Wrong ! ", vbCritical +          vbMsgBoxRight, " Error Login "
    Else     
        Set RS = Nothing
        Set DB = Nothing
        MDIForm1.Show
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    POOLCONNECTION
End Sub

Private Sub text1_keypress(keyAscii As Integer)
    If keyAscii = 13 Then
        Text2.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub text2_keypress(keyAscii As Integer)
    If keyAscii = 13 Then
        Command1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think, In your `Users` table you should use `nvarchar` type for `UserName` and `Password` fields ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove unnecessary spaces before and after `text`s:

```
SQLS = "Select * From Users Where Username = '" & Text1 & "'  And  Password = '" & Text2 & "' "
```